# How to use the id of an HTML instead of an inputId of a shiny input in a reactivity?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to create an `HTML` object within R to have more flexibility with `JS` code. However, I don't know how to introduce the id's of objects created with the HTML function inside `reactive()`. I compared two cases. One with `HTML()` and one with `textInput()`. In the first case it doesn't work, in the second it does. I need to use `HTML()` and not `shiny tags` because I need to edit my code in more specific parts.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  HTML(
  "<p>Type your name:</p>
  <input id='inputxaxis'></input>
  <br>"
  ), 
  
  valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box1", width = 6),
  
  textInput(
    inputId = "works", 
    label = "type your name:"
  ), 
  
  valueBoxOutput(outputId = "box2", width = 6),
  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  code1 <- reactive({
    fx <- function(x) {
      x
    }
    fx(
      x = input$inputxaxis # doesn't work
    )
  })
  
  code2 <- reactive({
    fy <- function(y) {
      y
    }
    fy(
      y = input$works # rorks perfectly
    )
  })
  
  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = code1(), 
      subtitle = "Subtitle", 
      color = "red"
    )
  })
  
  output$box2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = code2(), 
      subtitle = "Subtitle", 
      color = "green"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a JavaScript listener to send the input changes to the shiny server:

```
HTML(
    "<p>Type your name:</p>
    <input id='inputxaxis'></input>
    <br>
    <script>
    document.getElementById('inputxaxis').addEventListener('change', sendToShiny);
    
    function sendToShiny(event){
      console.log(event);
      Shiny.setInputValue('works_2', event.target.value);
    }
    </script>
    "
  )
```

Then you can access the input as you normally would:

```
code1 <- reactive({
      
      req(input$works_2)
      
      fx <- function(x) {
        x
      }
      fx(
        x = input$works_2
      )
    })
```

See more documentation here: [Communicating with Shiny via JavaScript](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html)

Comment: This is a really useful link but I think actually in this case you don't need to do it. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think Ryan Morton's answer is really good for understanding how Shiny works and quite likely you will need to use the information in the link for your actual use.

However, in this particular case you can just replicate the html that is created by `textInput()`. You can see what this is if you run your line directly in the R terminal (i.e. with the Shiny package loaded but not as part of a Shiny app):

```r
textInput(
    inputId = "works",
    label = "type your name:"
)
```

Output:

```html
<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
  <label class="control-label" for="works">type your name:</label>
  <input id="works" type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>
</div>
```

If you simply change the input id to `inputxaxis` and pop that in to replace your existing `HTML()` function call, then as you've already written the rest of the code it should replicate the behaviour.

```r
HTML(
        '<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
        <label class="control-label" for="works">type your name:</label>
        <input id="inputxaxis" type="text" class="form-control" value=""/>
        </div>'
    )
```